# Best practices for streaming videos to a large concurrent user base?

Tags: apache, html5

What are the best ways to stream videos for a user base of more than 1000 users?

What among the below would be the best way to use?

1. An html tag to embed the video in the source element.
2. To use a custom player like video.js, JWPlayer, media (IMO this is almost similar to the html tag)

or is there any other usual way of doing it?

The main objective is to concurrently cater video streaming to simultaneous server hits.
Currently with html5 `video` tag the video doesn't start if the same video is played in two tabs. It plays serially (second video starts after the first finishes) rather than in parallel.

**Does having Apache as the server cause this scalability problem?**

Is the use of a media server like Red5 necessary for video streaming ?

Is the HTTP protocol good enough to stream videos?

FYI the server is Apache web server 2.4.2. The web server is hosted in Windows 2008 R2.
Bandwidth is more than 8 Mbps with around 1000 users hitting the server.

Comment: 1,000 users total or 1,000 concurrent?

Comment: Around 700 concurrent users. Any best practices to be followed to achieve optimal performance?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stream, then use red5.

[On the red5 wiki you can see an example how to use red5 for live streaming](http://red5wiki.com/wiki/Live_streaming).